Decomposing a sub-addative function into an addative function and a concave function
Let $X$ be some ground set, and let $f: 2^X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a set function. Call $f$ sub-additive if $f(A \cup B) \leq f(A) + f(B)$ for all $A, B \subseteq X$, and additive if this holds with equality for disjoint $A$ and $B$.
If $c: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is sub-additive (as a real valued function), and $f'$ is a additive set function, the clearly $c\circ f'$ is sub-additive as a set function. My question is the converse, when is it possible to decompose a sub-additive set function $f$ as the composition of an additive set function $f'$ and a sub-additive real function $c$.
Clearly if $f(A) = f(A')$ and $f(B) = f(B')$ with $A\cap B = A' \cap B' = \emptyset$, then it must hold that $f(A \cup B) = f(A' \cup B')$. Are there any further restrictions? What if we want $c$ to be concave?
